# MediaPlayer error in eclipse when I try to reference a song

Tags: android, media-player

I'm trying to add background sound when my app starts up (main menu). I've researched how to do this and put it to work but I keep getting errors on eclipse. One suggestion was to put my music file in the res/raw folder of my project and reference it from there. All said and done, i get an error when I try to reference the song. R.raw.freezepop_starlight.mp3 gives me an error "the primitive type does not have a field mp3" .. does this mean I can't use an .mp3 file??? example code of how this is done will help.

MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.freezepop_starlight.mp3);

Answer (score 0):

Drop the `.mp3`. Resources are referenced without their extensions.

`MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.freezepop_starlight);`